# c# convert file from one format to another

Tags: c#, .net

i have a bunch of files that need to be converted. the beginning files look like this:

```
Well ID,Error code,Sample Barcode
A1,0,THC_CAL1
B1,0,THC_CAL2
C1,1,THC_CAL3
D1,0,THC_CAL4
E1,0,THC_QC1
F1,0,THC_QC2
G1,0,THC_QC3
H1,0,THC_QC4
A2,0,BLANK0609
B2,0,AA178121
C2,0,CC37815
D2,0,BLANK0610
E2,0,CC37819
F2,0,N150680
G2,0,BLANK0611
H2,0,AA127900
A3,0,AA26940
B3,0,BLANK0612
...........
```

the output needs to look like this:

```
A01 THC_CAL1
B01 THC_CAL2
D01 THC_CAL4   //please note that c1 is gone since it did not have a 0 in the middle column
E01 THC_QC1
F01 THC_QC2
G01 THC_QC3
H01 THC_QC4
A02 BLANK0609
B02 AA178121
C02 CC37815
D02 BLANK0610
E02 CC37819
F02 N150680
G02 BLANK0611
H02 AA127900
A03 AA26940
B03 BLANK0612
H10 BLANK0234 //please notice that there is H10 and not H010
```

what would be the best way to read this file into a variable and then output this into a new file? should i read it line by line or should i read it into a datatable?

Answer (score 2):

I would read the file a line at a time and check against this regular expression:

```
^([A-Z]{1})([0-9]{1}),0,([A-Z0-9_]+)$
```

If the line was a match, I would use the regular expression groups to output into your new format to the new file. (I'm sure it's not the best regex ever)

Basically, this is what you need to do, although i'm unclear where the last output line in your example came from.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("out.out")) // file to write to
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("input.dat")) //file to read from
                {
                    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([A-Z]{1})([0-9]{1}),0,([A-Z0-9_]+)$");
                    string line;
                    while (reader.Peek() > 0)
                    {
                        line = reader.ReadLine();
                        if (regex.IsMatch(line))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}0{1} {2}", regex.Match(line).Groups[1], regex.Match(line).Groups[2], regex.Match(line).Groups[3]));
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a StreamReader to read in the lines ONE LINE AT A TIME.  Parse the information you need. Construct the new line and write out to another file using a StreamWriter.  Do this all one line at a time.

Comment: Also, just split each line on commas. Regular expressions are overkill for this.

Answer (score 0):

Read into a datatable with OLEDB:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-using-the-built-in-oledb-csv-parser

Write out to a tab delimited file with OLEDB (about halfway down):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306023

Don't let the "Excel" part of this throw you...Excel uses the same provider (OleDb) as text files. You just need to construct the right connectionstring for the text file:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile

The OleDb Provider is good times.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is writing solid mapping rules, and there's nothing out there that will do that for you.  There are plenty of pattern-matching & conversion utilities to use, but for something this simple, .Net 3.0 & up core libraries contain more than enough tools to validate, format, filter, and sort any way you need.

So I would build types to explicitly represent the data.  Parse each line into an instance of your type.  Create a .ToNewType() method, or NewTypeClass(oldTypeInstance) whose concern is mapping from the old format to the new.

Once you have a List it is easy to save it out to a file.

Comment: im sorry i do not know how to do this can u please show me an example of how?