# C# Regex match case - split string and write to file output

Tags: c#, regex, split, match, streamreader

Basically I have a text file of records in this format:

```
(1909, 'Ford', 'Model T'),
(1926, 'Chrysler', 'Imperial'),
(1948, 'Citroën', '2CV'),
```

That I want to output to a text file in the following format

```
new Vehicle() { Id = 1, Year = 1909, Make = "Ford", Model = "Model T" },
new Vehicle() { Id = 2, Year = 1926, Make = "Chrysler", Model = "Imperial" },
new Vehicle() { Id = 3, Year = 1948, Make = "Citroën", Model = "2CV" },
```

I know I need to split each line in to the relevant text sections, e.g. trying to follow something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892750/c-sharp-convert-file-from-one-format-to-another) SO question. But have hit mental block on how to get the relevant matching string sections for Year, Make and Model.

So far I have found this, that finds everthing between the parentheses:

```
\(([^()]+)\)
```

But not sure how to then group the the values and split by the commas:

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can the quoted strings contain '(' or ')' ?

Comment: Is there always a newline after the `),`?

Comment: Well, if you want to use a regex, you may try [`^\((\d+)\s*,\s*'([^']*)'\s*,\s*'([^']*)'\),`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5c%28%28%5cd%2b%29%5cs*%2c%5cs*%27%28%5b%5e%27%5d*%29%27%5cs*%2c%5cs*%27%28%5b%5e%27%5d*%29%27%5c%29%2c&i=%281909%2c+%27Ford%27%2c+%27Model+T%27%29%2c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to get them in groups:

```
\((\d+),\s+[']([\w\së]+)['],\s+[']([\w\s]+)[']\)[,]*
```

Make note there is problem about Citro**ë**n => You have to enter all the special symbols not within a-z, A-Z (like ë ü ÿ etc..)

To use in code, You will get the groups 1st:

```
string cars = @"(1909, 'Ford', 'Model T'),"
string pattern = @"\((\d+),\s+[']([\w\së]+)['],\s+[']([\w\s]+)[']\)[,]*";
var lResult = Regex.Match(cars, pattern);

if(lResult.Success)
    foreach( var iGroup in lResult.Groups)
        Console.WriteLine(iGroup);
```

In lResult.Groups You got the info about car, You have just output it to the file as You need.

C# 6.0:

```
Console.WriteLine($"new Vehicle() {{ Id = 1, Year = {lResults.Groups[1]}, Make = \"{lResults.Groups[2]}\", Model = \"{lResults.Groups[3]}\"}},");
```

Old syntax:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"new Vehicle() { Id = 1, Year = "+ lMatch.Groups[1]+", Make = "+ lMatch.Groups[2] + ", Model = "+ lMatch.Groups[3] + " },");
```

Once You get this automatized into for loops, You can add Id easily.

My example have in Groups[0] whole string, so this is why my indexing starting from 1 to 3.

As @Toto said, `\w` already includes `\d`, there is no need to write it then.

Comment: Models may contain other characters than letter/digit

Comment: @Toto, thanks, haven't know about \d. And if there are other characters, we must have definiton what characters are they -> get it from some national/general alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use string.Split(',')? Would be faster than Regex and suits for you (first delete the last ',' of each line, of course.

Comment: And what is happening if there is a comma in the model?

Comment: His question is not clear, I don't know if he needs to read from text file to the modile or viceversa, but anyways, in either cases, he must have a deilmitar for the fields which is set to be unique

Comment: I could indeed use string split, but thought regex would be more concise approach to this?

Comment: Don't think so. Split is much more easy to read, and I think it's dessigned for these kind of cases.

I would let regex for more complex cases... Keep it simple

Comment: If You have stricly defined file, where they are written and there are not 2 spaces or so, it is simplier to use `Split()`. However `Regex` is more abstract and simply changeable solution to such case. If there is small change, You just change pattern. If it would be written by Split, You have to rewrite some more code.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved I would follow KISS principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

If the system pattern is the same always, why use regex? Harder to read, harder to main, not for this purpose. If your system changes in the future, then consider using regex, but don't use regex now because in the future it may change...

Comment: @JuanIgnacioCornet , TBH: I believe that `Regex` is much more clear, as You do the split/grouping in 1 command. If You do it over `Split`, it just gets dirty, You need to close the functionality in some method, etc.. Solution for this type of problem fits best each personal opinion. :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are willing to use a parser framework (which is maybe a little bit of an overkill), you could use for example [`sprache`](https://github.com/sprache/Sprache). Example without proper error handling:

```
Parser<string> stringContent = 
    from open in Parse.Char('\'').Once()
    from content in Parse.CharExcept('\'').Many().Text()
    from close in Parse.Char('\'').Once()
    select content;

Parser<string> numberContent = Parse.Digit.AtLeastOnce().Text();
Parser<string> element = stringContent.XOr(numberContent);

Parser<List<string>> elements =
    from e in element.DelimitedBy(Parse.Char(',').Token())
    select e.ToList();

Parser<List<string>> parser =
    from open in Parse.Char('(').Once()
    from content in elements
    from close in Parse.Char(')').Once()
    select content;

var input = new List<string> { "(1909, 'Ford', 'Model T')", "(1926, 'Chrysler', 'Imperial')", "(1948, 'Citroën', '2CV')" };

foreach (var line in input)
{
    var parsed = parser.Parse(line);
    var year = Int32.Parse(parsed[0]);
    var make = parsed[1];
    var model = parsed[2];

    Console.WriteLine(">> " + year + " " + make + " " + model);
}
```

Comment: `\w` already includes `\d`. You don't match `ë` in `Citroën` (depending on locale). Models may contains other characters than letter/digit

Comment: @Toto fixed via a generic tuple parser

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet based on named capture groups:

```
var cars = new List<string>() {
    "(1909, 'Ford', 'Model T')",
    "(1926, 'Chrysler', 'Imperial')",
    "(1948, 'Citroën', '2CV')",
};

var regex = @"(?<Year>\d+).*?'(?<Brand>.*?)'.*?'(?<Model>.*?)'";

foreach (var car in cars)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(car, regex);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{match.Groups["Brand"]} make {match.Groups["Model"]} in {match.Groups["Year"]}");
    }
}
```

Which will print:

> Ford make Model T in 1909
>
> Chrysler make Imperial in 1926
>
> Citroën make 2CV in 1948